# Key buttons not working

Tags: ignition-key, fob, central-locking

I have a 1999 model bmw e46 320i. Both My key remote buttons open the doors, windows and trunk. The buttons on both keys however does not lock the car again resulting the windows not to close while the BMW logo is depressed or the alarm to switch on. I have tried resetting the keys with the turning of the ignition,  removing the key, keeping the open button depressed and pushing on the bmw logo three times. The locking system does not ackowledge by unlocking and locking again. Nothing happens. It remains the same. Any other Help please!

Comment: Does the car lock if you lock manually?

Comment: Its likely the button inside the remote is bad. You can replace these if you can work a soldering iron. Else just get  new key from dealer or locksmith,

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have, but I feel like I have to ask... Did you check the battery?

When this happened to me I took the key apart and checked the battery, it was good, BUT, moisture got into it and left corrosion on the battery terminals so the electricity was not getting to the control board.

Good luck!

Comment: The OP states that the keys open the car... so no power seems unlikely...

Answer (score 0):

Standing in front of the vehicle, point the key at the interior mirror in the centre of the windscreen and try.  When the key power gets low, I can't lock mine when the key is below the level of the glass.

The key charges when it's in the ignition and the car is running so it's worth swapping keys regularly.  If it hasn't been used in a while, it's common that the key will go flat.